# Get all text between brackets if first bracket is missed with Regex

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I'm trying to write regexp, that can match all text between brackets and brackets too. But with one condition: first bracket can be missed. 
For example:

*Today is [sunny day]*

and

*Today is sunny day]*

In first case I wanna get *[sunny day]*. In second I wanna get *Today is sunny day]*.

I wrote regexp but it work only in first case.

`(?(?=\[).*?|)\]`

I tried to set else action like this

`(?(?=\[).*?|.*?)\]`

but in this case I got *Today is [sunny day]* instead of just *[sunny day]*.

Is there a regular expression that can solve my problem?

Comment: `(\[.*?\]|^[^\[\]]*\])` maybe works?

Comment: `\[?[^\]\[]*\]` should be enough.

Comment: thanks both work!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that nested brackets aren't to be considered you can simply use

```
\[?[^\]\[]*\]
```

or with a little less escaping

```
\[?[^][]*]
```

This will optionally match an opening square bracket, any content that doesn't contain a square bracket and the closing square bracket.

See https://regex101.com/r/97F2wM/1

(added `\n` to the negated character class to avoid line overlapping)